# jQuery and XML : Select by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have problem with XML and jQuery. This is is my code XML:

```
    <items id="2" name="name2">
        <opis></opis>
        <zdjecie></zdjecie>
    </items>

    <items id="3" name="name3">
        <opis></opis>
        <zdjecie></zdjecie>
    </items>

    <items id="4" name="name3">
        <opis></opis>
        <zdjecie></zdjecie>
    </items>
</sterowniki>
```

And this is my jQuery script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
      $(document).ready(function() {  
        $.ajax({  
          type: "GET",  
          url: "dbtest.xml",  
          dataType: "xml",  
          success: parseXml  
                });  
                function parseXml(xml) 
                {  
                       $(xml).find("sterowniki").each(function() {
                       alert("sterowniki"); 
                        $(xml).find("items").each(function() {
                        $("#nazwa").append('<h3 align="center"class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6     col-md-6 col-lg-8"><b>'+$(this).attr('name')+'</b></h3>');     
                        });
                     });
                  }
              });
          </script>
```

I have a problem with the display name. The website needs to load in such a way that when you first load the link elements (name, description), only the first element with id = 1 should be loaded. After the entry into another element, it should load the description and name of another on the same page. I am facing problems writing such a script where the choice of the appropriate elements is to be made depending on the click on the appropriate link.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an XML document, an `id` attribute is only that. It has no special meaning without an XSD that defines it. The standard identifier attribute is `xml:id` - a special attribute in the reserved namespace.

You can change the attribute or use an attribute selector.

```
$(xml).find('items[id="1"]');
```

To trigger the loading bind an click handler to each generated h3. The following example will trigger only an alert to keep it small:

```
$(xml).find('items').each(
  function() {
    var $items = $(this);
    var id = $items.attr('id');
    $('<h3></h3>')
      .appendTo('#nazwa')
      .text($items.attr('name'))
      .bind(
        'click',
        function() {
          alert(id);
        }
      );
  }
);
```

Comment: Now displays;) but my question is how to add loops that will automatically select an item in which I click? and display the name. As this site has to vary depending on the selected and clicked the link.
Thanks

Comment: I added an example generating elements from the XML and binding a click handler to them.

Comment: By using appendTo() and not append(), you keep the generated node in the jQuery object and can manipulate it.